# Adding own Router to Xfinity XB6 Gateway using Bridge Mode but not Xfinity App

Tags: networking, bridge-router

I have a new Xfinity service installed which works pretty well, but needed some extra functionality (guest network, eventually network isolation) and bought an Asus RT-55 Router.
Researching how to connect the two, let me to:

1. Put the Gateway into Bridge mode (which has a base IP address of 192.168.0.1)
2. gave the RT-55 a LAN IP address of 192.168.0.5
3. connected RT-55 from Gateway LAN port (1) to RT-55 WAN port
4. Set RT-55 WAN to ON and DHCP set to ON

Problem: when connecting my PC (or the Network I have with multiple computers and IP-Cameras) I do not get any internet access, even though the RT-55 App says Internet is active. My PC also says internet is active but I get no connections to any public websites (such as DuckDuck or WUnderground etc etc)

Questions:

- Does the new Router have to be 'Activated' by Xfinity?
- Are my Static IP-assignments incorrect?

Comment: I would ask your ISP for help. Modem Bridged mode as I know it and have it here has an external IP address, not a non-routable internal IP.

Comment: Could you explain please which may answer my ip assignment question.  Contacting internet provider so far only gave me non-helpful bot chat

Comment: When my ISP sets up Bridged Mode I get an External IP on the WAN interface of my router.

Comment: Should I have posted this at another section of the forum. Would think I am not the only one using a personal router with a company supplied gateway?
I spent 55 minutes with Xfinity support with not much advancement.

Comment: This is the correct section. I am surprised the ISP did not hep you. My own ISP sets up Bridged Mode readily for me.

Comment: TY all for your comments.  I reset the Router to it's original settings, and restarted the router which this time gave me a "automatically detect modem settings" choice (which I did not get the first time), and the rest was cake!  I changed login info, IP settings, security settings and a guest network and have 4 Linux PC's one Win10, several apples and 12 security cameras all working perfectly!   Again, TY for comments